# Run a curl tlsv1.2 http get request in python?

Tags: python, json, http, curl, tls1.2

I have the following command that I run using curl in linux.

```
curl --tlsv1.2 --cert ~/aws-iot/certs/certificate.pem.crt --key ~/aws-iot/certs/private.pem.key --cacert ~/aws-iot/certs/root-CA.crt -X GET https://data.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8443/things/pi_3/shadow
```

This command returns JSON text that I want. However I want to be able to run the above command in Python3. I do not know what library to use in order to get the same JSON response.

P.S. I replace "data" with my account number in AWS to get JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it on my own I was able to successfully do it in python using the requests library.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://data.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8443/things/pi_3/shadow',
    cert=('/home/pi/aws-iot/certs/certificate.pem.crt', '/home/pi/aws-iot/certs/private.pem.key', '/home/pi/aws-iot/certs/root-CA.crt'))


print(r.text)
```